# Oracle DB built-in procedure/functions deprecated between 11g and 19c

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

We are about to start a POC migrating our Oracle DB 11g to 19c. Are there any built-in procedures/functions that have been deprecated and are no longer available? I'd like to tell our development team about them now, rather than have them find out after migration.

Comment: You will have to read the release notes for Oracle 12.1, 12.2, 18 and 19 to find this.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was hoping someone had already done the heavy lifting and put together a summary.

Answer (score 0):

Read ["Chapter 10: Behavior Changes, Deprecated and Desupported Features for Oracle Database" of the 19c "Database Upgrade Guide" book.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/upgrd/behavior-changes-deprecated-desupport-oracle-database.html#GUID-3BAFD95E-4D00-4F0F-BC80-6064F497F878) There is a separate section for features deprecated and desupported in 12.1, 12.2, 18c, and 19c. Although that chapter is a "summary", you're still in for a few hours of reading.

In my experience, most of the upgrade problems fall on the administrators and there's very little work developers need to do. The most likely problems are with the function `WM_CONCAT` (that was never supported anyway), and some of the LogMiner features that could be used for change tracking.